# UnicodeDecodeError 'ascii' codec, but I'm not using ascii..am I?

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm a little confused about the following error:

```
utf_msg = msg.encode('utf-8')
```

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 48: ordinal not in range(128)

I chose utf-8 as the codex. Why is it talking about ascii when I am encoding?

Edit:

```
msg = (self.Name).encode('utf-8') + " - " + set + " changed from " + test.encode('utf-8') + " to " + value.encode('utf-8')
```

Data comes from a lot of sources. Oddly it works most of the time...there's just something I am parsing that is giving me trouble.

Comment: What is msg? Is it ascii encoded?

Comment: Maybe partially, a lot of info comes from other places:
msg = (self.Name).encode('utf-8') + " - " + set + " changed from " + test.encode('utf-8') + " to " + value.encode('utf-8')

Comment: is this python 2 or 3?

Comment: I don't know Python 2 (nor 3), but it looks like you are calling `.encode('utf-8')` on the output of  `.encode('utf-8')`. Also `test.encode('utf-8') + " to "` doesn't seem to make sense here. Is a Python 2 string an array of bytes with a default encoding of either ASCII or UTF-8? Concatenation of a UTF-8 string with an ASCII string, concatenates the bytes and results in a string with a default encoding of ASCII? (If this is correct, feel free to make an answer out of it. I hope this "outsider's point of view" is helpful.)

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. Some interesting questions I don't know the answer to. Maybe I can do some testing around that and it will help me get things straight.